# Python: What to do after the script development is complete, and where to schedule it

Tags: python, github, automation, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

Not really a technical question, but I feel quite lost at this point. I have completed a few courses on python, GIT, and have basic understanding of the functionalities. I have made a few python projects, that are in separate repositories, that I would like to put on schedule so that they would run automatically.

I have tried AWS, GIT actions, and raspberry PI, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong as it is quite hard for me to get the desired result.

Do python scripts have to be compiled? I have no experience in professional python development, so I wonder how it is done properly in companies. I assume that automating something through python is done on a regular basis, and for that the code has to be hosted somewhere, and also run somehow.

Perhaps there are some courses / websites / sources that you could recommend?

Answer (score 1):

As you outlined that you want to output csv , you need to store it somewhere ( or upload via e.g. POST request )

You might have "easy" success when using github actions and keep your csv as artifact [as described here](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/run-python-github-actions/)

( you should outline what your program should do ,

- provide an api -> then go for e.g. flask hosting
- run as cron    -> install it in any environment where you can run a script
  )

Comment: In my particular case the script scrapes some data and outputs it as a new csv file

Comment: ( updated , of course you can also just run it on your pi with `python3 myprogram.py` and keep the csv locally  ,it would be cool if you mark my answer as solution :D )